# Have xml load with page that flash will read from?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flashvars

Here's my problem that I have been trying unsuccessfully to find a solution for. I am building some flash menus that are going to pull from what I was hoping to be an xml file, but the client I am building it for doesn't have the fastest database in the world so when the page loads flash, it still takes a while to load the xml. This is undesirable as the viewer has already waited to load the page and now they're forced to wait for it to load again. I am trying to find a way for the page and the xml to be loaded together for flash to be able to read. I have explored flash vars, but it doesn't look like that was set up to contain an entire xml document as special characters break the html, which is the same reason why I couldn't make it all parameters instead of xml.

Does anyone know a way to get the xml loaded with the page, or another way of getting rss-like information into flash so that flash has it's content immediately?

Comment: There's a few easier options, like caching the XML file somewhere on the server so that it's not generated every time someone accesses the website.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. I'll have to see if I can do that. wordpress might have a plugin for that

Comment: is an RSS cached, or is it refreshed every time?

Comment: Depends on the application generating it. I don't have experience with Wordpress, so I can't comment there.

Comment: You can still use flashVars if you urlencode the xml.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get the urlencode code to not break the flashvar code. just dropping it in is enough to make it stick out like it's not part of the parameters.

Comment: if you have an example of how it can work I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

What's your coding environment? You're referring to your client's database and flash slow loading times, this shouldn't really be related. What data is Flash loading from the database?

One way to get your XML to load as quickly as possible is to use some form of preloader movie. This movie would have two functions:
- 1 Load XML data
- 2 Load MainMovie

This first movie would load very quickly since you could keep the graphic assets to a minimum, namely a simple progress bar/message informing the user that the main swf is loading.

Whilst the main movie is loading , you should have retrieved and parsed the XML data so that you could assign the resulting data to the loaded SWF.

Here's a condensed version:

```
     //Preloader
     private var menuData:Object;

     public function Preloader()
     {
           loadXMLData();
           loadMainMovie();
     }

     private function loadXMLData():void
     {
         var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); //etc...
     }

     private function xmlLoaded( event:Event ):void
     {
         menuData = parseXMLData( event.target.data );
         //remove listener
     }

     private function loadMovieComplete(event:Event ):void
     {
         var main:MovieClip = event.currentTarget.content as MainClass;

         if( menuData != null )
         {
             main.menuData = menuData;
             addChild( main );

         }else{

            //if your XML takes more time to load than your MainMovie
            //you may have to reconsider your options!
            //in any case you could add a listener here
            //to check when the xml load is complete
         }
         //remove listener
     }
```

Comment: i was shown a way in php to create a static xml that isn't refreshed by the user everytime it's called. So I think that's the way I'm going to go. I appreciate the response and know about preloaders, the problem is that the flash is only an element on the page, not the entire page, so I didn't want to have parts sitting there loading.

Comment: Whether Flash is part of the page or an element in the page is irrelevant. Don't forget that you're loading the main swf anyway, the solution above is a standard approach when loading a large swf and avoiding the user staring at a blank screen for too long. The user, or your HTML will never know about parts, this is all handled within Flash...